# Can you use <xsl:for-each> to go through attributes?

Tags: xslt, foreach, xslt-2.0

Is it possible to use the  command on attributes? I want this to be able to run without knowing the attribute names. Here's a quick (terrible) example:

```
<candy hard="true" soft="false" stripes="true" solid="false">
```

In my head (this doesn't work) it should look something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="candy/@[@='true']">
```

Is there a way around this to run through attributes without knowing their name, or do I need to write each attribute being looked at?

Edit

Heres an example of me trying to create a variable out of the attribute name where value='true'

```
<xsl:for-each select="candy/@*[. = 'true']">
<xsl:attribute name="candytype"> 
   <xsl:value-of select="name()"/> 
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OP's comment:

> can I return each attribute name (not value) whose value='true'?

```
<xsl:for-each select="candy/@*[. = 'true']">
   <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
   <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each>
```

**In XSLT 2.0 simply evaluate this XPath (2.0) expression**:

```
candy/@*[. = 'true']/concat(name(.), ' ')
```

Comment: Dimitre - is it possible to create a variable out of the attribute name instead of displaying it? I've tried doing <xsl:variable name="candytype"><xsl:value-of select="name()" /></xsl:variable> but it doesn't work...

Comment: @user673869: Yes, this variable contains a sequence of strings, each string being a name of an attribute: `<xsl:variable name="vAttrNames" as="xs:string*" select="candy/@*[. = 'true']/concat(name(.), ' ')"/>`

Comment: Dimitre - I believe your code is written for XSLT 2.0. Could you write an example for 1.0?   Also, you gave me this website as a good reference tool for one of my previous questions: http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N5258.html. Is there another that would better explain what I'm trying to accomplish? Thanks!

Comment: @user673869: You tagged the question s "xslt-2.0". If this is by mistake, please, delete this tag and tag it as "xslt-1.0"

Comment: @user673869: in XSLT 1.0 just put the `xsl:for-each` inside the body of an `xsl:variable`.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is

```
<xsl:for-each select="candy/@*">
```

Comment: cool.. can I return each attribute name (not value) whose value='true'? something like this:   <xsl:for-each select="candy/@*[@*='true']"> ?

Comment: @user673869: To select the attribute *nodes* whose value is true, `select="candy/@*[. = 'true']"`. To select or return their *names* is a longer answer ... see Dimitre's answer.